# PHP variable into PayPal JavaScript

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal onto my website but I can't seem to figure out how in the world to get the sum into the popup from PayPal. I have tried inserting the `<?php echo $sum;?>` directly into the JavaScript but that did not work. Any help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

**My Code:**

```
<h2>Total:
<?php
    include('includes/placeorder.php');
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(product_price) as sum FROM cart WHERE sess_id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result == false) {
        $mysql_error = mysqli_error($con);
        echo "There was a query error: $mysql_error";
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['sum'];
        }
    }
?>
</h2>
```

**Line from PayPal:**

```
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'checkout',

        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '1'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I need the `amount:{value:''}` to be the value of the total from where I pulled the sum of the rows in my MySQL statement.

Comment: So, where are those code snippets in relation to each other? Same file? Different files? Where did the variable `$sum` come from?

Comment: It's the same file. ```$sum``` comes from the MySQL query in my coding.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to give us _all_ the relevant code (like how you're populating the `$sum`-variable etc) or we won't have a clue where the info comes from or how you populate the values.

Comment: It has the code pulling from MySQL and the code from PayPal. I edited to show the full PayPal script code. I don't use the variable $sum as I deleted it because it didn't work. It originally had it as ```$sum = echo $row['sum'];``` under where I had the original echo.

Comment: Store amount in hidden field assign it a ID. then fetch value stored in ID in your paypal JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning the result to `$sum` variable, you're echoing it out.

```
<h2>Total:
<?php
    include('includes/placeorder.php');
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(product_price) AS sum FROM cart WHERE sess_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result == false) {
        $mysql_error = mysqli_error($con);
        echo "There was a query error: $mysql_error";
    } else {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $sum = $row['sum']; // Assign the result to $sum to use it in your code
        echo $sum; // If you want to show total amount
    }
?>
</h2>
```

```
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'checkout',

        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '<?= $sum; ?>'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```